# How do I search and replace a pattern in text using regular expression in Python 3?

Tags: regex, search, python-3.x, replace

How do I search and replace a pattern in text using regular expression in Python 3 ?

```
import re
text = "|105_Oldtext1.1|309_Oldtext1.1|367_Newtext1.6|413_Newtext1.6|"
result = re.sub("105_*", "105_Newtext1.6", text)
print(result)
```

what I get as result is:

```
"|105_Newtext1.6Oldtext1.1|309_Oldtext1.1|367_Newtext1.6|413_Newtext1.6|"
```

I want to replace 105_(whatever text) by 105_Newtext1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` isn't a wildcard here ;) You might need this instead:

```
import re
text = "|105_Oldtext1.1|309_Oldtext1.1|367_Newtext1.6|413_Newtext1.6|"
result = re.sub("105_[^|]*", "105_Newtext1.6", text)
print(result)
```

`*` means that the previous character is repeated 0 or more times. So, `[^|]*` means any character which is not a pipe character being repeated 0 or more times.