# Search and replace a string pattern in python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regular expression in python which finds `</td= >` in the string and replace it with `</td>`. The position of the characters inside the angular brackets may change. for example: it may be `</t= d>` or `</= td>` and so on. One of the character in the angular brackets is whitespace. The regular expression should find any of these occurrences and replace it with `</td>`. There is on similar question on [How do I search and replace a pattern in text using regular expression in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468329/how-do-i-search-and-replace-a-pattern-in-text-using-regular-expression-in-python) but I am unable to figure out the answer. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this regex

```
<[\/td= ]{5}>
```

> https://regex101.com/r/T549ej/2

```
import re
string_to_process=r'</t= d> or </= td>'
substitute_string=r'</td>'
td_regex=re.compile(r'<[\/td= ]{5}>')
td_regex.sub(substitute_string, string_to_process)
```

---

For what you are asking in comments, use this regex:

```
<[^>]*?t[^>]*?d[^>]*?\/[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?t[^>]*?\/[^>]*?d[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?d[^>]*?t[^>]*?\/[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?d[^>]*?\/[^>]*?t[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?\/[^>]*?t[^>]*?d[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?\/[^>]*?d[^>]*?t[^>]*?>
```

see here: https://regex101.com/r/T549ej/4

```
import re
string_to_process=r'</t= d> or </= td>'
substitute_string=r'</td>'
td_regex=re.compile(r'<[^>]*?t[^>]*?d[^>]*?\/[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?t[^>]*?\/[^>]*?d[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?d[^>]*?t[^>]*?\/[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?d[^>]*?\/[^>]*?t[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?\/[^>]*?t[^>]*?d[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?\/[^>]*?d[^>]*?t[^>]*?>')
td_regex.sub(substitute_string, string_to_process)
```

Comment: This works. Just want to know if we can check whether the angular brackets contains characters `/td` at any position and we can replace the whole string with `</td>`. how to write a regular expression for this?

Comment: See now; besides the replacement, you want to know if is it the case that the three chars **/td** appears exactly in that order?

Comment: I want to check if the characters `/`,`t` and `d` are present inside the angular brackets at any position in any order then replace the whole string by `</td>`.

Comment: are you sure about that? at any position in any order? you have three chars, so, all possible orders are 6 (i.e 3! = 3*2*1)... Could be *<...t...d.../...>* , *<...t.../...d...>* , *<...d...t.../...>* , *<...d.../...t...>* , *<.../...t...d...>* and *<.../...d...t...>* , where **...** is anything, even, nothing... is that what you want?

Comment: Yes Sir. Ho do we write a regular expression for this in python?

Comment: Great!; two things: you can change the title of your answer, to reflect more precisely what you were trying to achieve, and you can mark my answer as the one resolved your problem